# .NET 6 XmlSerializer Pretty print

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I've this sample .NET 6 program printing out a serialised object to XML:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));

var order = new Order
{
    Address = new Address
    {
        FirstName = "Name"
    }
};

await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, order);

var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(result);

public class Order
{
    public Address Address;
}

public class Address
{
    public string FirstName;
}
```

This results in this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Address><FirstName>Name</FirstName></Address></Order>
```

In .NET 5 and .NET Core 3 similar code results in pretty printed XML like below. How can I format this XML in .NET6?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Address>
    <FirstName>Name</FirstName>
  </Address>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To write indented xml you can use `XmlTextWriter` (instead of just `StreamWriter`) with `Formatting` set to `Formatting.Indented`:

```cs
await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter streamWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
streamWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, order);

var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

**UPD**

As [@sveinungf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063618/sveinungf) wrote in the comment - using `XmlWriter.Create` is [recommended approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter?view=net-6.0#remarks), so the code can look like this (also note that `Create` method can accept `StringBuilder` or file name which can be more convenient in some scenarios):

```cs
await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var streamWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, new()
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Indent = true
});
serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, order);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Comment: Note that `XmlTextWriter` is [no longer recommended to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter). It is now recommended to use `XmlWriter.Create` instead.