# StreamWriter along with XmlSerializer in DotNet6 does not write WhiteSpaces?

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-6.0, streamwriter, xmlserializer

Actually I tried this basic code in C# which serializes the DataSet into XML document.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));

    // Creates a DataSet; adds a table, column, and ten rows.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("myDataSet");
    DataTable t = new DataTable("table1");
    DataColumn c = new DataColumn("thing");
    t.Columns.Add(c);
    ds.Tables.Add(t);
    DataRow r;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        r = t.NewRow();
        r[0] = "Thing " + i;
        t.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("DemoNet5.xml");
    ser.Serialize(writer, ds);
    writer.Close();
}
```

And this creates the "DemoNet5.xml" file with proper WhiteSpaces and Indentation in .NET 5. But When I try to run the same code in .NET 6
I am not getting the WhiteSapces and Indentation so that the contents    of the xml are written in single line.

Later on when I try to read that .xml document I face issues.
Is there someone who can help me with this ? I want my xml contents to be in proper format that is with proper indetation and WhiteSpaces.
[Xml file created using .NET6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owurW.png)
I have also attached the XML document created using DotNet6.

Comment: As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69441535/net-6-xmlserializer-pretty-print), you need to use `XmlWriter` instead of `StreamWriter` an set `Indent` to `true` (see the updated section of the accepted answer)

Comment: First of all, whitespace isn't significant in XML. Second, you didn't specify you want indentation so [the default (None)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmltextwriter-formatting) was used. Third, DataSet has a [WriteXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=net-6.0) method that can write to files, TextWriter or XmlWriter. You don't need XmlSerializer

Comment: No indentation has always been the default. Did you use different code in .NET perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No I used the same code there too, but I got the file with Indentation.

Comment: In that case .NET Core 3-5 changed the 20-year old behavior and .NET 6 reverted to it

Comment: @MindSwipe Yes That worked Thanks, but is there any way to make it work with StreamWriter instead of using XmlWriter ?

Comment: Why do you need to use StreamWriter?

Comment: @Magnus StreamWriter will be getting the data in chunk and so we will not be having any issues with the large files, but XmlWriter will get the whole data and try to write it to the file.

Comment: XmlWriter can take in a Stream as argument, I'm not sure but I think it will write to that in a similar manner.